# MySql Driver not loaded

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I use Visual Studio 2008, MySQL 5.0.90,Qt 4.6.3 and C++ 
 I try connect MySql  but it gives this error messages.

- Driver not loaded.

I am new programmer. How cann I solve this problem? Thank a lot.

Comment: Where do you get this error? In IDE or after you start your software? What do you use to connect to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I sloved this problem by uninstalling my existing Qt version and installing a newer Qt version.  In the new version the drivers were properly setup and everything worked flawlessly.